# Roots Of An Inseparable Polynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Suppose that we have a field $K = \mathbb{Z}_p(t)$ where $p$ is prime. (So this is the field of rational polynomials with $t$ as the variable)

Let $f = x^p - t$ be a polynomial in $K[x]$.

How can one describe the roots of $f$? I stumbled across this example but I was just wondering how the roots would look like.

An obvious root of $f$ is $\sqrt[p]t$, but what are the other distinct roots of $f$?

Comment: That’s the only root there is. That’s why it’s called inseparable.

Comment: Hint: $(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p$ in characteristic $p$.

Comment: @Lubin Hm, are you sure? I thought you can have multiple roots but they have to be of multiplicity of some common power of $p$.

Comment: @anon So in this case, would it mean that... that would mean that the roots of $f$ are of a power of $p$?

Comment: Um, $p$ equals $0$ in $\Bbb F_p$, and of course the roots are not powers of $0$. Use my hint to completely factor $x^p-t$ using only one root $\sqrt[p]{t}$.

Comment: When you write $\mathbb{Z}_p$, you mean $\mathbb{F}_p$, right? ($\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the p-adic integers)

Comment: @J.DavidTaylor Well, $\Bbb Z_p$ is used by many for what others (including me) call $\Bbb F_p$. More are aware of the finite field of order $p$ than are aware of the $p$-adic integers. Of course there is no ambiguity in this question: it must be the finite field of order $p$.

Comment: I'm a bit slow at seeing this but, if I said $\alpha$ was a root of $f$ that means that $(x - \alpha)^p = x^p - \alpha^p = x^p - t$ So that just means that $x$ only has one root and the multiplicity is $p > 1$?

Comment: Right. (Well, except you should say $f$ only has one root, not $x$.)

Comment: Woops wrong wording, but yep. I see it! Thank you. :P